# Migrating to Ruby 2.0.0 with Rails 3.2: how to set up tmp dir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-2.0, tmp

I just migrated to Ruby 2.0.0 from 1.9.2 and I'm getting errors when trying to handle files because I can't get tmp directories to work.

If you check [this file](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/tmpdir.rb?v=2.0.0-p247) and look at line 29 you'll see that they've added a check on `world_writable?`, but they want the file to not be world writable (prepended by !). So they want a restricted tmp dir? How do I set that up for Rails?

Here's the error I get:

```
ArgumentError: could not find a temporary directory
```

When I try to hit `Dir:tmpdir`

```
/home/ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb: in tmpdir
raise ArgumentError, "could not find a temporary directory" if !tmp
```

Comment: Do you have a log or an error message that you can share?

Comment: Fixed in Rails 4 apparently.